# Rails - exclude a specific element from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have method in my model that returns an array called `all_items` 
I'm trying to filter out the insurance item if the duration is more than 365 days so as below:

```
  def available_items
    return all_items - [all_items.insurance] if duration >= 365

    all_items
  end
```

But I'm still getting insurance even if the duration is more than 365. Tested it in the console and insurance comes up as part of the array. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: _"I have method in my model"_ – show it, please. Since this is a Rails question I suspect that you retrieve the array from your database? If so, you'd typically use a _query_ to specify the records you're interested in, probably via a _scope_.

Comment: Well, the addition with the id 28 in the one array is not the same as in the other array, they have different object ids. Where do these arrays come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to simply negate your scope:

```
def available_items
   duration >= 365 ? Addition.where.not(id: Addition.insurance) : Addition.all
end
```

Though it might be more efficient to create a negative scope on your model, eg:

```
scope :not_insurance, -> { where.not(name: 'insurance' }
```

and then change the available_items to something like:

```
duration >= 365 ? Addition.not_insurance : Addition.all
```

Answer (score 1):

`Addition:0x00007f8655402300` is not the same as `Addition:0x00007f86526cc728`

You could check the `name` instead of the whole object:

```rb
  def available_items
    return all_items.reject { |i| i[:name] == "insurance" } if duration >= 365

    all_items
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that it is not `Array` but `Relation` and `insurance` is the scope.

So you can do something like

```
all_items.where.not(name: 'insurance')
```